# Can we get auto conversion of mana and tap symbols?

Tags: feature-request, magic-the-gathering, formatting

For example, convert the text {1}{G}{U}{B}{R}{W}{T} to [image: 1 Colorless Mana][image: Green Mana][image: Blue Mana][image: Black Mana][image: Red Mana][image][image: Tap]

If we can't use the actual symbols, then maybe just the letter/number on a colored background (preferably a circle)? [image]

Comment: Don't forget the rest of the possible symbols while you are at it. You have multi-color symbols, generic/split colored symbols, 1-20 generic symbols, phyrexian symbols, the untap symbol, and probably a few others I'm missing.

Comment: This is another of those 'important' requests. It's possible the symbols themselves can't be used due to copyright issues, but surely alternative placeholders can be found. If there were support from a dev on this, I'm confident the community could provide a complete list of required conversions.

Comment: Is this actually needed? Anyone have a list of questions that would have actually benefited from this feature?

Comment: @ColinD an answer I recently wrote (for http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13520/underworld-connections-tapping-the-land-for-mana-and-ability) would be much more readable with this feature

Comment: Here's a question where mana symbols were so essential, multiple answers used images:  https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/45595/9999 .  Dedicated support would make this much easier

Answer (score 2):

If we can use the actual symbols, I can see this as being helpful for some questions.

If we cannot use the actual symbols, I see no point in this feature. Why make people learn another symbol? The text representation of mana symbols { {B}, {U}, {W}, {R}, {G}, {1} } are used in the comprehensive rules.

Further, would we want to do this for all mana/tap symbols or just the basic ones? The list of mana symbols will quickly grow when we start to include the 1-15+ colorless mana symbols, dual mana symbols, phyrexian mana symbols, ect... What do we do when WotC decides to add more symbols to the game? Can we commit to updating our MTG symbols every couple months?  I do not know how the script/icons are implemented on SE sites, but my guess is no.

Comment: It makes questions with Mana symbols easier to read. For example {U} is blue, but some people may not know that. Also it would standardize the way it is written. It may be in the comprehensive rules, but still not obvious to everyone.

Comment: How would the Blue mana symbol re represented if we created our own icons? a Blue ciricle with a B, or a Blue circle with a U?

Comment: The colorless mana symbols should be easy to render without having a separate icon for every single one. [Here, I generated one for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/42uCC/1/) Admittedly, it looks poor for 2 digit numbers, but Stack Exchange doesn't pay me to fix that.

Comment: @Rainbolt: That looks kind of broken for me (Firefox 31 / Linux). [Here's my attempt at basic iconless CSS mana symbols.](http://jsfiddle.net/NCC6H/) It should even be possible to do hybrid mana symbols that way, although it gets a bit trickier. And of course the symbols themselves could be added by various means.

Comment: Ps. [Here's an improved version](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwz8f/) that supports hybrid mana, phyrexian mana, half mana (from Unhinged) and has a fancy Unicode tap symbol. All that with just pure HTML + CSS, no images!

Comment: Pps. ...and [here's yet another version](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc48b/) with webfont support and a JS routine to convert `{1}{G}{U}{B}{R}{W}` shorthand to icons.

Comment: There's also untap ({Q})